# How to connect to my computer from a chromebook via SSH?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, chromebook

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop and I'd like to be able to remote into it when I'm on the road. How can I set up my desktop to allow me to connect remotely from my Chromebook via SSH? How long would it take to go through the setup process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install the openssh-server with the following command on your desktop

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

After the installation is complete (it just take about a minute), you should be able to SSH to it by:

`ssh USERNAME@IP`

USERNAME is the username on your desktop system, IP is its IP address.

Comment: You'll also need to port forward to be able to access your computer from outside your home network.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too complicated. Here's quite a good tutorial on it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWr6VCgLxBs